# How to replace repeated NaNs with a different value from lone NaNs from Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, repeat

I have several timeseries arranged in a data frame, similar to below:

```
   category value   time_idx
0   810     0.118794    0
1   830     0.552947    0
2   1120    0.133193    0
3   1370    0.840183    0
4   810     0.129385    1
... ... ... ...
6095 1370   0.157391    1523
6096 810    0.141377    1524
6097 830    0.212254    1524
6098 1120   0.069970    1524
6099 1370   0.134947    1524
```

Some values are NaN. What I would like is to replace any NaN values that are NOT repeated with 0, as I am assuming the value is 0 for that category at that time. However, any time that every single category has a value of NaN at that same time (i.e. at the same time_idx), then I want to replace every value with -1.

Just replacing the NaNs with a value is of course trivial in Pandas, but the added complexity of specifically replacing NaNs that are NaN for every category at a given time has stumped me. I know I can just loop through the time indices, but my actual datasets will have over 900 categories, so I would like to find a more efficient Pandas-esque method.

The only thing I could think of was list comprehension, which I don't think is even necessarily more efficient than an explicit loop anyway, plus I couldn't come up with one that worked properly.

I know that I can just replace all NaNs like so:

`data["value"] = data["value"].replace(np.nan, 0)`

but I'm not sure how to implement this in my case, where I only want to replace long NaNs with 0. This is the loop I have currently:

```
num_channels = data["category"].nunique()
nan_vals = data[lambda x: np.isnan(x.value)]
nan_times = nan_vals["time_idx"]

for time in nan_times:
        if nan_vals[lambda x: x.time_idx == time]["category"].nunique() < num_channels:
            # Set 0 for every channel that has nan at time t
            index = nan_vals[lambda x: x.time_idx == time].index

            data.loc[index, ["value"]] =  data.loc[index, "value"].replace(np.nan, 0)

        else:

            index = nan_vals[lambda x: x.time_idx == time].index
            data.loc[index, ["value"]] = data[lambda x: x.time_idx == time]["value"].replace(np.nan, -1)
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Here is an example:

given the following data frame:

```
    category    value   time_idx
0   810          NaN    0
1   830          NaN    0
2   1120         NaN    0
3   1370         NaN    0
4   810      0.129385   1
5   830          NaN    1
6   1120     0.144378   1
7   1370         NaN    1
8   810      0.124334   2
9   830      0.487274   2
10  1120     0.119153   2
11  1370     0.871687   2
```

I would like this output:

```
    category    value   time_idx
0   810        -1.000000    0
1   830        -1.000000    0
2   1120       -1.000000    0
3   1370       -1.000000    0
4   810         0.129385    1
5   830         0.000000    1
6   1120        0.144378    1
7   1370        0.000000    1
8   810         0.124334    2
9   830         0.487274    2
10  1120        0.119153    2
11  1370        0.871687    2
```

In this example, at time = 0 every category's value was NaN, so they would be replaced with -1. At time = 1, there were non-NaN values, so any NaN values present (category 830 and 1370) would be replaced with 0.

Comment: Hi Ryan, have you tried something that we can look into?

Comment: Hi Anwarvic, Thanks for your response. I was able to successfully implement it by looping through every time but as I mentioned I would like to do it more efficiently. I will append my question with some more details of my ideas.

Comment: @RyanDempsey Can you show the sample of the input dataframe and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find those `time_idx` where all entries are NaN using `groupby` and then `group.isna().all()`. You can use that mask to fill the NaNs with `-1`.

Afterwards fill all other NaNs with `0` using `fillna`.

```
all_nas = df.groupby("time_idx").value.apply(lambda group: group.isna().all())
df = df.set_index("time_idx")
df.loc[all_nas, "value"] = -1
df = df.reset_index().fillna(0)
print(df)

#     time_idx  category     value
# 0          0       810 -1.000000
# 1          0       830 -1.000000
# 2          0      1120 -1.000000
# 3          0      1370 -1.000000
# 4          1       810  0.129385
# 5          1       830  0.000000
# 6          1      1120  0.144378
# 7          1      1370  0.000000
# 8          2       810  0.124334
# 9          2       830  0.487274
# 10         2      1120  0.119153
# 11         2      1370  0.871687
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `time_idx` and iterate over groups.
Then in each group count number of `NaN` values in `value` column.
Depending on the number of nans one can update `value` column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'category': [810, 830, 1120, 810, 830, 1120, 810, 830, 1120],
        'value': [None, None, None, 1, 2, None, None, None, 4],
        'time_idx': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    }
)

print(df, end='\n\n')


for name, group in df.copy().groupby('time_idx'):
    num_nans = group['value'].isnull().sum()
    mask = (df['time_idx'] == name) & df['value'].isna()
    if num_nans == len(group):
        df.loc[mask, 'value'] = -1
    else:
        df.loc[mask, 'value'] = 0

print(df)
```

Output

```
   category  value  time_idx
0       810    NaN         0
1       830    NaN         0
2      1120    NaN         0
3       810    1.0         1
4       830    2.0         1
5      1120    NaN         1
6       810    NaN         2
7       830    NaN         2
8      1120    4.0         2

   category  value  time_idx
0       810   -1.0         0
1       830   -1.0         0
2      1120   -1.0         0
3       810    1.0         1
4       830    2.0         1
5      1120    0.0         1
6       810    0.0         2
7       830    0.0         2
8      1120    4.0         2
```